# Show Shipping name instead of invoice name in Order List Prestashop Back Office

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop, e-commerce

Is there any easy way to show shipping person Name in Order List of Prestashop BO? To search an order by Shipping person name.

Searched Google & and asked for help on Prestashop forum but return value 0 :D

Help Will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Prestashop 1.6

Comment: You should look in /controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php. Add your new field to `$this->fields_list` array in the `__construct()` function. You will probably need to modify the SQL query at the beginning of constructor. I don't know if there is an easier way.

Comment: i have tried in many ways in AdminOrdersController.php but i don't have enough knowledge to do it. Looking for help. Is anyone there?